# Why is a struct with const members assignable?

Tags: c++, c++11, type-traits

I needed to use the `std::is_assignable` type traits, which happens not to be available in the oldest compiler version that I want to support. Since I had to implement this myself (okay, I admit it, there was some interwebs peeking), I now wonder if this is a bug in my implementation or a general problem of `std::is_assignable`.

First of all, this is my test struct:

```
struct Bar {
  bool const cb; // this should kill the default assignment operator
  int i;
};
```

and here is my `stdreplace::is_assignable`

```
template <typename T> struct is_assignable : private std::__sfinae_types {
  private:
    template <typename T1> 
      static decltype(std::declval<T1>() = std::declval<T1>(),__one()) test(int);
    template <typename T1> 
      static __two test(...);
  public:
    static bool const value = sizeof(test<T>(0)) == sizeof(__one);
};
```

However, it tells me, `Bar` is assignable:

```
int: 1
Bar: 1
int[2]: 0
```

Where is the problem?

Comment: Did you try changing your boolean variable name to be somthing else than a reserved keyword?

Comment: @pwny: Oh boy. It was a typo *in the question*, because I typed the `Bar` struct by hand. I corrected the question, **thanks**!

Comment: Hehe all good I was just making sure this wasn't some weird compiler trick acting up because of this.

Comment: With copy ellision this code is valid. You need to do some tricks with a function body to make sure a copy happens.

Comment: @Dani: Sorry I don't get it, what does the one have to do with the other?

Comment: @bitmask: a copy/assigment doesn't happen in your code

Comment: What have you done in order to verify that your hypothesis (that `Bar` variables *aren't* assignable) holds?

Comment: @molbdnilo: Try to assign a `Bar` to another `Bar`. Also it's common knowledge :)

Comment: Tested on g++ 4.7.0 I get `0`, so there is no problem with what you have shown (but I just tested on ideone (gcc 4.5.1) and got 1 so I think it might be a compiler problem).

Comment: @Jesse: g++ 4.5.2 seems to optimise the assignment away. Apparently it was fixed in newer versions to support this approach.

Comment: @bitmask: My bad. I missed the bit where you deliberately didn't define the assignment operator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your compiler probably does not correctly define the assignment operator as deleted. In c++03 code with respect to implicitly declared special member functions, such an assignment within an unevaluated operand was fine even if the assignment would be illformed if it occurs in an evaluated operand. The reason for that is because the asignment operator would never be implicitly defined but only implicitly declared thus never rising an error.

Since that changed in c++11 and your assignment operator should be deleted automatically it appears to me that your compiler is at fault.

Comment: I see. I suspected as much, because further investigation and different attempts made one less sense than the previous, thanks for the confirmation. I'd file a bug report, but apparently it is already fixed in newer versions.